# jquery + ie7 = undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

i'm having strange problem in ie7 with a jquery. the problem occurs only in IE7. In short (ie9 compatibility turn to ie7) console window shows that jQuery is not defined - however jQuery (1.7.1) is loaded (from disk not cdn) and i can view it from debug window in IE.

yo can view page here:
http://karolwasik.pl/works/familypark/

there's only a few lines of code js used with default html5boilerplate package (like modernizr), also i've used jQuery Cycle Plugin.

these few lines are (so you can see that additional coma is not the issue ;) ):

```
/* Author: karolwasik.pl */
$(function(){

$('#batonP').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    h = $('#subpC .slajdM').height()
    log(h)
    log($(this))
    if(h!==633){
        $('#subpC .slajdM').stop().animate({'height': 633}, 150)
        $(this).removeClass('nieaktywny').addClass('aktywny')
    } else {
        $('#subpC .slajdM').stop().animate({'height': 233}, 150)
        $(this).removeClass('aktywny').addClass('nieaktywny')
    }
})
if($('#frontnav').length){
    fv = $('#frontnav').find('li').get()
    //$('#frontnav').html('')
    $('#mainC').cycle({ 
        fx:     'fade', 
        speed:  1000, 
        timeout: 0,
        next: '.nextS',
        pager: '#frontnav',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {  
            return $(fv[idx]); 
        }    
    }); 
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have imported all these files after the footer.

```
<!-- scripts concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
  <script defer src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>  
  <script defer src="js/libs/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>  
  <script defer src="js/plugins.js"></script>
  <script defer src="js/script.js"></script>
  <!-- end scripts-->
```

where as the the modernizr is there in the beginning. I would suggest to move all the scripts on the header. try to keep the modernizr at the bottom or in the middle of the above scripts and check if it works.

Comment: nope it's not the issue. also i see why to move modernizr, modernizr should be loaded first and at last jquery and rest (that's why defer is used on them ;) )

Comment: Oh I get that. But as such there are no errors on the page and the JQuery should render fine... I ll get back to you as I figure it out.